# Attempting to add GCCelendar into my app

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an app with 5 tab bars, the 3rd one is where i want to put the calendar in.
I have a seperate class for the implementation of the tab bar but how do i go about implementing the calendar into the subview of the tabbarview controller?

```
@implementation CalendarDayView

@synthesize managingViewController;

- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.managingViewController = aViewController;
        self.title = @"Day";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //GCCalendar *calendar = [[GCCalendar alloc] init];
    GCCalendarPortraitView *calendar = [[GCCalendarPortraitView alloc] init];// autorelease];
    calendar.dataSource = self;
    calendar.delegate = self;
    calendar.hasAddButton = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:calendar];
    //[self.view addSubview:calendar.view];
    //[self addChildViewController:calendar];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    frame.origin.y = -20.0f;
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Heres what my class looks like. I also should mention that this view is of a segmented button action. I have a list view day view and month view. Im currently working on the day view.

If anyone has questions or opinions please tell me. Please stay away from using nib files also. thank you. I am a new to objective-c as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Just add the above to - (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the header view working but the grid view is nowhere to be found.

GCCalendarPortraitView *calendar = [[GCCalendarPortraitView alloc] init];

```
calendar.dataSource = self;
calendar.delegate = self;
calendar.hasAddButton = YES;
[self.view addSubview:calendar.view];
//[self.view addSubview:calendar.view];
[self addChildViewController:calendar];
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
frame.origin.y = -20.0f;
self.view.frame = frame;
```